# Optional Type (_all) in NEST - Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I Nest, how do you produce this request:

```
GET demo_covariant/_all/2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
client.Get<dynamic>(2, g => g
    .Index("demo_covariant")
    .Type("_all")
);
```

Change `dynamic` to whatever type is expected (`dynamic` will work, will be a Json.NET `JObject`).

[The client supports search to return covariant types.](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/2.x/covariant-search-results.html) Covariance is not supported for responses that return a single type.